# Why doesn't Jquery fadeOut() work? Hide() does

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, fadeout

After an Ajax result I'm trying to fadeOut a html button. This works most of the time, however sometimes the button isn't faded out and I can't figure out why.

```
$.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action')+'?time='+timestamp,
    data: frm.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if(data['success'] === true){
            hideSaveButton();
        }
    }
});

function hideSaveButton(){
    $('#saveBtn').fadeOut(250);
}
```

Accessing the hideSaveButton() function doesn't seem to be a problem. It's just the fadeOut() function that isn't working. I tried replacing fadeOut() by hide() which works without any problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show more code there is no error hope in the full code there is error.

Comment: could you show us the html/css as well? (maybe simulate your issue in a jsFiddle?) this would be really usefull

Comment: Do you use it like that http://jsfiddle.net/5Urnx/2/ ?

Comment: `$('#saveBtn').stop().fadeOut(250);` Maybe there are too many calls in succession?

Comment: @abhitalks Thanks, this seemed to be the solution. Can you post this as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the calls are being made in quick succession. Which means that the `fadeOut` fires before the earlier one has finished.

You may want to `stop()` before you attempt the `fadeOut()`:

```
$('#saveBtn').stop().fadeOut(250);
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1):

Hans,

There's no need to put your

```
if(data['success'] === true) {
```

block in your code, this is handled by your success: callback and your if statement will never return false. Instead you should simply have two callbacks like the following:

```
success: function(data) {
    // My success code
},
error: function(data) {
    // My error code
}
```

But back to the question, is there anything wrong with simply using the hide like this?

```
$('#saveBtn').hide('fade', 250);
```

Is it possible that your server is returning an error during these times where you observe the undesired behavior? It would prevent the success: callback being reached and the hiding of the element.

Comment: Thanks, your hide example returned an error: Uncaught TypeError: Property '250' of object #<Object> is not a function.

Other than that there were no errors returned and a console.log() test was shown succesfully inside hideSaveButton().